# DATEDIFF() seconds with millisecond to float or decimal

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, type-conversion

How to convert the below code to float or decimal type?

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(ss, StartTime, GETDATE()) + '.' + 
       DATEDIFF(ms, StartTime, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I needed. `CONVERT(float, DATEDIFF(ms, StartTime, GETDATE()) / 1000.0)`

The code i my question was completely wrong because `DATEDIFF(ms, StartTime, GETDATE())` returns total number of milisecond between the two dates and not as i thought only difference in the milliseconds part.

The code im my question would work if I used the `DATEPART` instead `DATEDIFF` in both expressions:

```
DATEPART(ss, GETDATE()) - DATEPART(ss, @StartTime) + '.' 
+  DATEPART(ms, GETDATE())  - DATEPART(ms, @StartTime)
```